# Can anyone recommend me an example for electron desktop app to sent data to a mobile app made using Angular ionic Cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, electron

I am currently doing a project, a part of it is where I need to send data from the electron app to a ionic angular Cordova app I made. The electron app stores the parameter of time, toggle, PWM value, and time schedule, where it can be sent to the mobile Cordova and the mobile app saves the info via WIFI. Can anyone give some guidance in implementing or example code to use for me to implement this.

Comment: you can use Push Notifications or simple REST Api to get data in your mobile application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, do you have any recommendation for resources that can help me implement these functions in electron and angular ionic Cordova?

Comment: do you have any backend server for this application?

Comment: No, I'm quite new to doing this. and its just to send small amounts of data.

Comment: you have to have a backend server to transfer your data from your desktop application to mobile application. You can make simple nodejs server or Firebase database to transfer your data.

Comment: OK, noted so something like MongoDB should work as well right? If so thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yes. you can use mongDB.